# Should mmap in HotSpot JVM be with MAP_ANONYMOUS?

Tags: jvm, mmap

I want to mmap to a file or a block device.
So, I modified HotSpot code, function named commit_memory_impl() to be without MAP_ANONYMOUS.
However, JVM failed with SIGSEGV.

If I append the MAP_ANONYMOUS, it works.
Should I use mmap with MAP_ANON? in JVM?

Comment: I'd say you should never try to modify HotSpot code unless you are 100% sure what you are doing. What goal do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mmap a file I would use the built in libraries to do this.

Note: This is limited to less than 2 GB at a time however if you use reflection like [Chronicle-Bytes](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Bytes/blob/master/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/bytes/MappedFile.java) does, you can map 63-bit regions.

This doesn't require you to modify the JVM.